# How to resolve 'Expect' in NEST elasticsearch 2.3.1

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

[NEST lasticsearch doc](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/docs/client-concepts/high-level/mapping/auto-map.asciidoc)

In this NEST elasticsearch documentation there is an example am trying to use and am not able to resolve this line. in which assembly do I get the Expect?

Expect(expected).WhenSerializing((ICreateIndexRequest)descriptor);

thanks.

Comment: var descriptor = new CreateIndexDescriptor("myindex")
    .Mappings(ms => ms
        .Map<CompanyWithAttributes>(m => m.AutoMap())
        .Map<EmployeeWithAttributes>(m => m.AutoMap())
    );

var expected = new
{
    mappings = new
    {
    .
    .
    }
};

Expect(expected).WhenSerializing(descriptor as ICreateIndexRequest);

Comment: The `Expect()` call is there to assert that the serailized `descriptor` matches `expected` when serialized to json. The documentation is generated from tests. You won't need `Expect()` in your code :)